# Best way to copy members from vector<Class> to vector<Member_Type>

Tags: c++, algorithm, copy, stdvector, std

I have a vector of complicated structs (here `std::pair<int, int>`). I now want to copy a member (say `std::pair::first`) into a new vector. Is there a better (more idiomatic) way than

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> list = {{1,2},{2,4},{3,6}};

std::vector<int> x_values;
x_values.reserve(list.size());
for( auto const& elem : list )
{
    x_values.emplace_back(elem.first);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) is often used for exactly this:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>  // transform
#include <iterator>   // back_inserter

// ...

std::vector<int> x_values;
x_values.reserve(list.size());

std::transform(list.cbegin(), list.cend(), std::back_inserter(x_values),
               [](const auto& pair) { return pair.first; });
```

Comment: Great, exactly what I had in mind!

Comment: Okay, moved... ;)

Comment: Would  `[](const auto& pair)` work here?  (I genuinely don't know)

Comment: @PaulSanders Yes, that'll work too. Added.

Comment: ... And could bung in a call to `reserve` before calling `std::transform` ...

Comment: @PaulSanders Indeed. Sloppy copying from OP:s original on my part. :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Never explain, never apologise :)

Comment: Also, as a twist on this which might offer better performance, see: https://wandbox.org/permlink/DE7qY8cRWYUEWu1S (and, with `cbegin`, `const auto` is inferred Ted, sorry about that).

Comment: @PaulSanders Yes, I've experimented some with similar solutions to allocate and skip the `back_inserter` and it sometimes improves things. I doesn't work in all cases though (non-default constructibles) and sometimes doesn't improve things. Never apologise :) The extra `const` just makes it extra clear that it's `const` :-)

Comment: Yes, if T has an expensive default constructor (or none at all, of course), then this might be counter-productive.

Answer (score 4):

In [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) using [`std::ranges::views::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/transform_view) and range algorithms one might do

```
#include <ranges>    // std::views::transform
#include <algorithm> // std::ranges::copy

std::vector<int> x_values;
x_values.reserve(list.size());

std::ranges::copy(std::views::transform(list, [](const auto& pair) {
    return pair.first; }), std::back_inserter(x_values));
```

or may be a just view over the pair.first (if the indention is to have a read only range)

```
#include <ranges>    // std::views::transform

const auto x_values_view = std::views::transform(list, [](const auto& pair) {
        return pair.first; }
);
```

[Live Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/de9jKb3Eh)

Comment: Like the second offering, not so sure about the first (seems more complicated to me than Ted's answer).

Comment: @PaulSanders I agree; However, just adding the alternative for the future readers.